# React Native Google Mobile Ads not working. After installing npm add react-native-google-mobile-ads I got some errors please check the below error

Tags: firebase, react-native, admob, create-react-app

After installing the *npm add react-native-google-mobile-ads* I got the error. I posted here the errors please check, Here I added my android build.gradle file and App level build.gradle file
*how can I specify compileSdkVersion? *

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
        -----------
        * Where:
        Build file 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ReactNative\Firebase\hellworldfirebaseeekkl\node_modules\react-native-google-mobile-ads\android\build.gradle' line: 75
        * What went wrong:
        A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-google-mobile-ads'.
        > Cannot get property 'googleMobileAdsJson' on extra properties extension as it does not exist
        * Try:
        > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
        > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
        > Run with --scan to get full insights.
        ==============================================================================
        2: Task failed with an exception.
        -----------
        * What went wrong:
        A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-google-mobile-ads'.
        > compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
        * Try:
        > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
        > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
        > Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

*My APP (build.gradle file)*

```
android {
        ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
     defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.hellworldfirebaseeekkl"
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED", isNewArchitectureEnabled().toString()
    if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
                // We configure the NDK build only if you decide to opt-in for the New Architecture.
                externalNativeBuild {
                    ndkBuild {
                        arguments "APP_PLATFORM=android-21",
                            "APP_STL=c++_shared",
                            "NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang",
                            "GENERATED_SRC_DIR=$buildDir/generated/source",
                            "PROJECT_BUILD_DIR=$buildDir",
                            "REACT_ANDROID_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid",
                            "REACT_ANDROID_BUILD_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/build",
                            "NODE_MODULES_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules"
                        cFlags "-Wall", "-Werror", "-fexceptions", "-frtti", "-DWITH_INSPECTOR=1"
                        cppFlags "-std=c++17"
                        // Make sure this target name is the same you specify inside the
                        // src/main/jni/Android.mk file for the `LOCAL_MODULE` variable.
                        targets "hellworldfirebaseeekkl_appmodules"
```

*My android project build.gradle file*

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31

        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == "aarch64") {
            // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
            ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
        } else {
            // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
            ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        }
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
```

Comment: I solved this error by adding app id in App.json file but now I am getting new error please help- 

     WARN  `new NativeEventEmitter()` was called with a non-null argument without the required `addListener` method.

    WARN  `new NativeEventEmitter()` was called with a non-null argument without the required `removeListeners` method.

Answer (score 7):

Within the root of your React Native project, open the app.json file and add the android_app_id & ios_app_id keys with the IDs from the Google AdMob console:

```bash
// <project-root>/app.json
{
  "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx",
    "ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

Copy
If you're an expo user, make sure the react-native-google-mobile-ads block is outside of the expo block! It should look like this:

```bash
// <project-root>/app.json
{
  "expo": {
    // ...
  },
  "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx",
    "ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

Copy
For the changes to take effect, rebuild your project:

```bash
# For iOS
npx pod-install
npx react-native run-ios

# For Android
npx react-native run-android

# For expo users not using EAS
npx expo prebuild

# For expo users using EAS
npx eas-cli build --profile development
```

More: https://docs.page/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads#setting-up-google-admob

Answer (score 1):

In my case I used test android_app_id provided by Google in my AdMob account and they caused crash. Then I found another testing ad ids:

```
"react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713",
    "ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511"
  }
```

and they worked.